# Programmatic web browser Java library

Tags: java, browser

Does anyone know of any Java library for programmatic web browsing?

[Prowser](http://prowser.sourceforge.net/) doesn't cut it because there's no "push the button" method and [Watij](http://watij.com/) is limited to Internet Explorer Windows only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

htmlunit?

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

The above link says:

> ... HtmlUnit is not a generic unit testing
>   framework. It is specifically a way to
>   simulate a browser for testing
>   purposes...

Comment: HtmlUnit with all of it's dependencies takes 7.6MB. I guess it's not particularly lightweight.

Comment: Only if it loads all of those. The size of the jars does not dictate how big the resultant executable is (leaving aside the actual VM size)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find some of what you want in [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and especially when using Selenium Server like in [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cq04037/)